# Why are many system calls (getpid) captured only once using strace?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, libc, strace

I invoked *getpid()* in a program for many times (to test the efficiency of system calls), however when I use `strace` to get the trace, only one *getpid()* call is captured.

The code is simple:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_usage(){
    printf("Usage: program count\n");
    exit(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2)
        print_usage();
    int cnt = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i = 0;
    while(i++<cnt)
        getpid();
    return 0;
}
```

I used `gdb` and got this:

```
(gdb) disasse
Dump of assembler code for function getpid:
0xb76faac0 <getpid+0>:  mov    %gs:0x4c,%edx
0xb76faac7 <getpid+7>:  cmp    $0x0,%edx
0xb76faaca <getpid+10>: mov    %edx,%eax
0xb76faacc <getpid+12>: jle    0xb76faad0 <getpid+16>
0xb76faace <getpid+14>: repz ret 
0xb76faad0 <getpid+16>: jne    0xb76faadc <getpid+28>
0xb76faad2 <getpid+18>: mov    %gs:0x48,%eax
0xb76faad8 <getpid+24>: test   %eax,%eax
0xb76faada <getpid+26>: jne    0xb76faace <getpid+14>
0xb76faadc <getpid+28>: mov    $0x14,%eax
0xb76faae1 <getpid+33>: call   *%gs:0x10
0xb76faae8 <getpid+40>: test   %edx,%edx
0xb76faaea <getpid+42>: mov    %eax,%ecx
0xb76faaec <getpid+44>: jne    0xb76faace <getpid+14>
0xb76faaee <getpid+46>: mov    %ecx,%gs:0x48
0xb76faaf5 <getpid+53>: ret
```

I don't quite understand the assembly code. It would also be helpful if somebody can give some detailed explanation about it. According to my observation, "call *%gs:0x10" (, which jumps into vdso) is not executed, except for the first *getpid()* call, that may be the reason why subsequent *getpid()* calls are not captured. But I don't know why.

The linux kernel: 2.6.24-29
gcc (GCC) 4.2.4
libc 2.7,

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glibc caches the result, since it can't change between calls. See the source code [here](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.23/sysdeps_2unix_2sysv_2linux_2getpid_8c_source.html) for instance.

So the real syscall only gets executed once. The other calls just read from the cache. (The code is not very simple because it takes care of doing the Right Thing with threads.)

Comment: Great. And I have another question; it may be not relevant. I'm wondering whether even the first getpid() call doesn't trigger user-kernel mode switch by leveraging vdso, as for gettimeofday?

Comment: Another question is how can I single step into "call   *%gs:0x10" using gdb?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single answer to that. syscalls are handled differently depending on the platform (i.e. even 32bit x86 and 64bit x86_64 have different syscall mechanisms). But maybe I'm wrong - you should probably post a separate question for that, and do specify which architecture(s) you're interested in, and what syscalls if there are some you're especially interested in. (i'm don't know gdb very well at all)

Comment: @SIFE: not that I'm aware of and I don't see any reason they would provide that feature - a process's PID never changes.

Comment: @Mat But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @SIFE: As I said, don't think there is.

Answer (score 4):

glibc caches the pid value. The first time you call getpid it asks the kernel for the pid, the next time it just returns value it got from the first getpid syscall.

glibc code:

```
pid_t
__getpid (void)
{
#ifdef NOT_IN_libc
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_DECL (err);
  pid_t result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (getpid, err, 0);
#else
  pid_t result = THREAD_GETMEM (THREAD_SELF, pid);
  if (__builtin_expect (result <= 0, 0))
    result = really_getpid (result);
#endif
  return result;
}
```

If you want to test the overhead of syscalls, `gettimeofday()` is often used to do just that - the work done the kernel is very small, and neither the compiler nor the C library can optimize away calls to it.

Comment: You cannot use the `gettimeofday()` function to mesure syscall overhead, since `gettimeofday` is not a standard syscall on Linux: it is optimized through the vDSO mechanism. On my laptop, a standard syscall lasts for about 225 ns, whereas `gettimeofday` lasts only for 20 ns.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, with the introduction of pid_namespaces and numerous bug detected in applications on signal receipt or when they create child processes by calling *[syscall()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)* instead of *fork()*, *vfork()* and *clone()*, the pid is no longer cached in the GLIBC. This is pointed out in the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html):

> From glibc version 2.3.4 up to and including version 2.24, the
> glibc wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, with the goal of
> avoiding additional system calls when a process calls getpid()
> repeatedly.  Normally this caching was invisible, but its correct
> operation relied on support in the wrapper functions for fork(2),
> vfork(2), and clone(2): if an application bypassed the glibc
> wrappers for these system calls by using syscall(2), then a call
> to getpid() in the child would return the wrong value (to be
> precise: it would return the PID of the parent process).  In
> addition, there were cases where getpid() could return the wrong
> value even when invoking clone(2) via the glibc wrapper function.
> (For a discussion of one such case, see BUGS in clone(2).)
> Furthermore, the complexity of the caching code had been the
> source of a few bugs within glibc over the years.